# Azure | Token for Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory

To get the Token API I should use:
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANT_ID]/oauth2/token

But I don't have

```
- APP_ID
- PASSWORD
```

I should use an APP registration. But I don't have permission to it.

Using the CLI command:
`az account get-access-token`
I can get the Token. And it works fine for my purpose.

But, how can I get the access-token, as this command does? 
Without the `API_ID/CLIENT_ID and SECRET`?

Since this command is able to do, there is probably a way, maybe using my email/pass?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD without client id(Application id) you can not get access token for you are Application.

Token request details for [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request)

In the case of the client secret, it is not mandatory always and it depends on the [code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) .

The command  `az account get-access-token` is used to   get a token for utilities to access Azure.

Comment: But I need this "token for utilities to access Azure". How can I get it without the command? Is there a way to get it from an API call or something?

Comment: what is the resource you want to access in azure?

Comment: any idea how I can get the token? Since this command is able to get it from my computer. there is probably a way to do it

Comment: Both Azure and Azure AD are different. The command az account get-access-token comes under Azure but Application ID(client id) comes under Azure AD